# Selenium : Code not up to the mark comments on my code

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Recently I have started learning selenium and I have applied to the job.
They asked me to write code for CRUD operation for this website
http://computer-database.herokuapp.com/computers

I am pasting the code here.Although it was running fine on my machine and I used framework as well.

Can anyone help me what is not up to the mark because I have been asked to write down code for the second interview and I don't want to repeat my mistake.

Looking forward for your help.

```
public class Add {

    public static WebDriver driver; 
    public static WebDriver getdriver(){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
            "/Users/sonali/Downloads/geckodriver"); 
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        return driver;
    }

    @Test(priority=1) //Create a computer
    public static void create(){
        driver=getdriver();
        driver.get("http://computer-database.herokuapp.com/computers?f=ACE");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();    
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='add']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='name']")).sendKeys("newtest");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='introduced']")).sendKeys("2017-03-20");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='discontinued']")).sendKeys("2017-03-29");
        Select s= new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("company")));
        s.selectByValue("2");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/form/div/input")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/div[1]")).isDisplayed();
        System.out.println("Creating data is working");     
    }

    @Test(priority=2)     //Search for a computer and check its available 
    public static void read(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchbox']")).sendKeys("newtest");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchsubmit']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("newtest")).click();
        System.out.println("Reading data is working");      
    }

    @Test(priority=3) // Update a computer name and company
    public static void update(){
        driver.findElement(By.id("name")).sendKeys("one");
        Select s= new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("company")));
        s.selectByValue("5");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/form[1]/div/input")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/div[1]")).isDisplayed();
        System.out.println("Updating computer is working fine");

    }       

    @Test(priority=4) // Deleting computer from the list
    public static void delete(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchbox']")).sendKeys("newtestone");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='searchsubmit']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("newtestone")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/form[2]/input")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/div[1]")).isDisplayed();
        System.out.println("Deleting computer is working fine");
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not an appropriate forum for this type of question.

Comment: @sonaliarjun Good Question +1

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

For the code to be actually useful, it needs to be :

1. Readable
2. Maintainable
3. Structured properly

Try developing a framework for the tests i.e.:

1. Separate the driver generation to a driver factory class.
2. Separate the selectors and the respective actions to some other functional or page based classes.
3. Use assertions to verify. (an exception not appearing does not mean the functionality is working)
   e.g.

> driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/div[1]")).isDisplayed();

It will not matter what it returns as the code does not do anything with it.
It should be -

> Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='main']/div[1]")).isDisplayed());

Or better yet-

> Assert.assertTrue(updatePage.isupdateDisplayed());

4. Try putting comments in the code which might make it more easy to understand
5. Run tests through a runner / xml.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @amita said in her answer.
There is a lot you can do to improve on your code but it will take a bit of study, so not sure if you'll be able to follow my advice in time but hopefully this will be helpful to further your understanding of test automation with Selenium WebDriver.

1. Learn about the **Page Object Model** design pattern. This is probably the most popular design pattern used with WebDriver. There are lots of free tutorials online but [here's a good one to get you started.](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/)
2. Once you have a good idea of Page Object Model you can enhance it by learning about **LoadableComponent**. Again lots of free tutorials online, [here's one I picked at random](http://blog.wedoqa.com/2014/10/simple-and-advanced-usage-of-loadablecomponent/)
3. You're using XPath extremely heavily. Make sure you understand the preferred hierarchy of locator methods and use them appropriately. **ID should be your first preference.** XPath and CSS you last resort. For example,

   ```
   By.xpath(".//*[@id='add']") //Never use this
   By.id("add") //When you could have just used the ID locator
   ```
4. Study how TestNG works, in particular **Annotations** like **@BeforeTest**,
   **@AfterTest**, and so on. Your tests should be independent, so avoid setting them up in such a way that they require you to force their priority order. [It's well documented here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) but again lots of tutorials online to help you through it.

There's more but if you get your head round all that you'll have a very good base from which to build further. I wish you all the best with your interview

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Considering it as a Interview Question and writing it at a Interview Venue, I think you have done a commendable work.

A few words about the solution:

1. As you integrated **`TestNG`**, apart from `@Test` Annotation consider using `@BeforeTest` and `@AfterTest` Annotation and **`Assert`** Class too.
2. Consider generating some log messages to the console which helps in debugging your own code.
3. Consider moving the `WebDriver` instance initialization within `@BeforeTest` annotation.
4. Consider starting your `@Test` with **`priority=0`**.
5. Your `xpath` like `.//*[@id='add']` are not proper, consider using valid `xpath` e.g. `//input[@id='name']`
6. Induce proper **`ExplicitWait`** i.e. **`WebDriverWait`** while trying to search for elements on new webpages.
7. When perform some `@Test` try to validate the `Result` through **`Assert`** Class.
8. Consider adding the **`imports`** wisely.
9. Once you create a **`WebDriver`** instance consider releasing it after your `@Test` within `@AfterTest` Annotation.
10. Here is the minimal code to `Create a Computer` by the name **`Debanjan`**

    ```
    package demo;

    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
    import org.testng.Assert;
    import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class Q44852473_GOOD_CODE_sonali_arjun 
    {
            public static WebDriver driver; 
            String myname = "Debanjan";

            @BeforeTest
            public void initDriver()
            {
                System.out.println("=====Test Started=====");
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe");
                System.out.println("=====Initializing Webdriver=====");
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            }

            //Create a Computer
            @Test(priority=0) 
            public void create()
            {
                driver.get("http://computer-database.herokuapp.com/computers");
                driver.manage().window().maximize();    
                driver.findElement(By.id("add")).click();
                WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait (driver, 10);
                WebElement name = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='name']")));
                name.sendKeys(myname);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='introduced']")).sendKeys("2017-07-01");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='discontinued']")).sendKeys("2017-07-01");
                Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("company")));
                select.selectByValue("1");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='btn primary']")).click();
                WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait (driver, 10);
                WebElement searchbox = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='searchbox']")));
                WebElement add_success_ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//section[@id='main']/div[@class='alert-message warning']/strong"));
                String success = add_success_ele.getText();
                Assert.assertTrue(success.contains("Done"));
                System.out.println("Computer "+myname+" -  created Successfully");     
            }


            @AfterTest
            public void tearDown()
            {
                driver.quit();
                System.out.println("=====Test Completed=====");
            }
    }
    ```

### Enhancements:

1. This Solution can be modified by using other **`TestNG`** annotations documented [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations).
2. This Solution can be enhanced by implementing through **`POM (Page Object Model)`** documented [here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/page-object-model/).
3. This Solution can be further enhanced by implementing **`POM through PageFactory`** documented [here](http://www.guru99.com/page-object-model-pom-page-factory-in-selenium-ultimate-guide.html).

Let me know if this Answers your Question.